# How to verify whether the poolpingquery configuration in the mybatis configuration file is executed correctly?

Tags: mysql, mybatis

Under the default settings of MySQL, when a connection is idle for more than 8 hours, MySQL will disconnect the connection. So I added the setting of poolpingquery in the configuration file of mybatis, but I found that the project still reported like`"The last packet successfully received from the server was 43200 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 43200 milliseconds ago".` I doubt whether the poolpingquery setting of mybatis takes effect.

So I printed out the sql log executed by mybatis, and found that the poolpingquery statement was not executed as expected.Below are the poolpingquery parameters I configured and the test code. Is the test method wrong?Or the ping statement cannot be printed out in the log？

Configuration:

```
   <property name="poolPingEnabled" value="true"/>
   <property name="poolPingQuery" value="/* ping */ SELECT 1"/>
   <property name="poolPingConnectionsNotUsedFor" value="100"/>
```

TestCode:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SqlSession sqlSession = SqlSessionConfig.getSqlSession();
        MidCountryDictMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(MidCountryDictMapper.class);
        while (true){
            Integer integer = mapper.selectCount(null);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

log configuration:

```
module.log=com.p6spy.engine.logging.P6LogFactory,com.p6spy.engine.outage.P6OutageFactory

logMessageFormat=com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.p6spy.P6SpyLogger

deregisterdrivers=true

useprefix=true

excludecategories=info,debug,result,batch,resultset

dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

outagedetection=true

outagedetectioninterval=2
```

log:

```
     Warn: Could not find @TableId in Class: com.cn.hlx.mysql.entity.TargetClassDict
     Consume Time：43 ms 2020-08-25 18:01:13
     Execute SQL：SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM mid_country_dict
    
     Consume Time：31 ms 2020-08-25 18:01:18
     Execute SQL：SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM mid_country_dict
    
     Consume Time：32 ms 2020-08-25 18:01:23
     Execute SQL：SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM mid_country_dict
    
     Consume Time：34 ms 2020-08-25 18:01:28
     Execute SQL：SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM mid_country_dict
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. To help you answer your question you need to provide some more information. How did you configure Logging in MyBatis?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the engine kills the sessions periodically, as long as you are using datasource. The datasource will take care of checking the connections in the pool are alive and will reconnected them behind the scenes for you if they are dead. Are you using a datasource? Is the pool big enough?

Comment: @BjörnRaupach   HI，I used p6spy to print logs.I have updated the configuration information to the question.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks for your answer!I used the connection pool of mybatis, the connection pool size is sufficient. In order to solve the problem that the idle connection is closed, I set the poolpingquery parameter according to the official document of mybatis. Now I have a question about how to detect whether the program executes the ping query according to the parameters I configured, because the log I printed did not execute select 1 Sentence

Comment: @fishhami If you enable DEBUG logging for [`org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/cb11469b3118c5d1d0501c489dcfe196d7c8568d/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/datasource/pooled/PooledDataSource.java#L550-L563), there should be some output when ping query is executed. Please see the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html) for how to configure logging.